# Chrome: Websocket closing tab closes all other connections in all other tabs

Tags: java, google-chrome, websocket

Here is my `Java` endpoint

```
@ServerEndpoint("/tweets")
public class TweetStreamServer {
    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(TweetStreamServer.class);

    @OnMessage
    public void tweets(final String message, final Session session) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        System.out.println("session id:" + session.getId() + ", search term: " + message);
        final Client twitterClient = TwitterHoseBird.getInstance(message);
        while (!session.getOpenSessions().isEmpty()) {
            for (final Session s : session.getOpenSessions()) {
                if (twitterClient.isDone()) {
                    System.out.println("Twitter Client Done, waiting ...");
                }
                s.getBasicRemote().sendText(TwitterHoseBird.getMsgQueue().take());
            }
        }
    }
    @OnClose
    public void onClose(Session session, CloseReason reason) throws IOException {
        LOGGER.warn("closing session: {}, remaining session: {}", session.getId(), session.getOpenSessions().size());
    }
```

On Chrome, I do the following in 4 different `tabs`

```
var connection = new WebSocket('ws://127.0.0.1:8080/tweetstream-1.0-SNAPSHOT/tweets');
connection.onopen = function () {
  connection.send('germany');
};
connection.onerror = function (error) {
  console.log('WebSocket Error ' + error);
};
connection.onmessage = function (e) {
  console.log('Server: ' + e.data);
};
connection.onclose = function (e) {
  console.log('closing session');
};
```

All the tabs then receive data from Twitter.

If I do `connection.close();` on one of the tab, only that tab closes connection, but other 3 still receive the data.

However, if I **close the tab**, it **closes connections in all other tabs** by logging `closing session`

What is the issue here?

On server, when I **close tab**, I see log as

```
[0m[33m09:24:53,342 WARN  [com.self.tweetstream.TweetStreamServer] (default task-16) closing session: tulDjtq4Lx8s1Zo3mA2mwX8B, remaining session: 1
```

How can I make other connections live, even if any tab is closed?